# Could I ask for feedback/suggestions to improve an essay I wrote?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, critique

Could I ask for feedback/suggestions to improve an essay I wrote? I have been recently asked to do a practice write of an argumentative class in class. I have finished and turned it in. However, this essay will not be given any feedback from the teacher. Could I ask for advice or suggestions on the essay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry Max, but critique requests are off-topic on Writing.SE - from the Help Center, specifically the page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (original emphasis):

> ***On the other hand, these kinds of questions aren't allowed here:***
>   [...]
>   - [Requests to critique your work](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writing-se-accept-critique-requests/879#879) or [rephrase something](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic/537#537). However, please *do* feel free to use your own writing as *examples* in on-topic questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that I cannot ask these types of questions then. However, I would like to ask where can I ask these types of questions, if at all? +1

Comment: @Max0815 Sadly I am not aware of any site on the StackExchange network that would allow for such a critique. We sometimes get questions about where you could get feedback, such as [What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/904/23159) but that's quite old and I don't know how useful they are for an essay. If you have a question about how to make some *specific part* of your essay better you could ask here, but for a complete feedback / review I don't know any useful place. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. Check! Thank you very much for your feedback! :)